# Трансформации во ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

Возможно замылился глаз, но я никак не могу найти решение для своей проблемы. 
Итак:

Отправляется запрос на создание объекта на сервер. Если запрос выполнился удачно, вернется объект, который мы сохраняли. Если не удачно, то `null`. Во `ViewModel` есть полный список этих объектов. Нужно перехватить результат запроса на создание, обработать его, дополнить общий список объектов при необходимости и уведомить об этом фрагмент/активити.

Сейчас это cделано крайне костыльно:

После получения результатов запроса, во вью модели дергается метод на добавление нвоого значения. Я пробую скрыть это трансформацией, но что-то не попробую - все не то или вообще не работает.

Сокращенный код **ViewModel**:

```
class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var repository: Repository = App.repository

    var events: MutableLiveData<List<Event>> = MutableLiveData()
// костыльное добавление нового элемента к списку с данными. Дергается в observer createEvent(), во фрагменте
    fun addEvent(event: Event) {
        val eventsArrayList = ArrayList( events.value)
        eventsArrayList.add(event)
        events.postValue(getCorrectEvents(eventsArrayList))
    }

// запрос на обновление списка с данными
    fun getEventsListFor(userId: String, force: Boolean = false):
            MutableLiveData<List<Event>> {

        if (events.value == null || force)
            events = repository.getTodayEventsFor(userId)

        return events
    }

// запрос на создание
    fun createEvent(userId: String, event: Event): MutableLiveData<Event> =
            repository.createEvent(userId, event)
}
```

Я уже пробовал перепробовал первую страницу гугла, и результата нуль. В 90% случаях среда подчеркивает все красным. В 10% трансформация никак не тригериться.

Собственно: как менять `MutableLiveData` список прямо во вью моделе, по результату любого другого запроса? observe во `ViewModel` не работают, рекомендует использовать трансформации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, я решил проблему. Для этого я переписал метод создания, и добавил трансформацию внутрь:

```
fun createEvent(userId: String, event: Event): LiveData<Event> {
    return Transformations.switchMap(repository.createEvent(userId, event)) {
        if (it != null) {
            val eventsArrayList = ArrayList( events.value)
            eventsArrayList.add(it)
            events.postValue(getCorrectEvents(eventsArrayList))
        }

        MutableLiveData<Event>().apply { this.postValue(it) }
    }
}
```

Метод из **ViewModel**. Суть: выполняется запрос `repository.createEvent(userId, event)`, его результат перехватывается трансформацией. Далее результат обрабывается и при необходимости меняется лист евентов. В завершении результат возращается в обсервер в активити/фрагменте.

Так же я приведу пример более простой трансформации, когда выполняется запрос, и нужно отфильтравать данные.

```
var otherRooms: LiveData<List<Room>> = Transformations.switchMap(getRoomsState()) { rooms ->
    val other: MutableLiveData<List<Room>> = MutableLiveData()
    other.postValue(rooms.filter { it.email != ROOM_NAME })
    other
}
```

где `getRoomsState()`:

```
var rooms: MutableLiveData<List<Room>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getRoomsState(): MutableLiveData<List<Room>> {
    if (rooms.value == null)
        rooms = repository.getRooms()

    return rooms
}
```

Не все пока идеально, но решение есть.